# Why does stripe.Account.retrieve("") return an account, and what account is it?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to make a utility function to check if a user has submitted their onboarding details.

Ex:

```
@property
def is_onboarded(self):
    stripe = stripe_config()
    a = stripe.Account.retrieve(self.stripe_user_id)
    return a.details_submitted
```

If `self.stripe_user_id` is an empty string, it returns some account for an ID I can't track down (don't see it in the online Connect interface).

Ex:

```
>>> stripe.Account.retrieve('')
<Account account id=acct_abc123abc1235N at 0x264b6b6cd00> JSON: {
  "capabilities": {
    "acss_debit_payments": "active",
    ...
```

My simple question is, why? And, what account is it returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the platform account (ie. your account; the one you're making the request with).

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. At: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account. Odd that it returns anything. Documentation says: "Returns an Account object if the call succeeds. If the account ID does not exist, this call raises an error."